# What's the etymology of "der Gaul" (the horse)?

Tags: meaning, etymology

There's lots of words for **horse** in German, including *"der Gaul"*. What is the etymology of this word?

Comment: Welcome to GSE. When you ask a question, please show whatever effort you already have invested into finding an answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just look up this kind of thing. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gaul#Etymology_2) says it's from Middle High German with a cognate in [Dutch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guil#Dutch). See [EWD](https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/Gaul) for more detail.

Answer (score 3):

You could have looked that up yourself in an [etymological dictionary](https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/Gaul):

> Gaul m. ‘minderwertiges Pferd, Mähre’; früher wie noch heute im Nordd. und Md. auch ohne geringschätzigen Sinn. Das Wort kommt nur im Dt. und Nl. vor (schwed. mundartlich gula ‘altes Pferd’ beruht auf Entlehnung aus dem Mnd.). Die ursprüngliche Bedeutung ist schwer zu ermitteln. Mhd. gūl bedeutet ‘Pferd’, zugleich ‘Eber’ (mhd. urgūl ‘alter Eber’) und ‘männliches Tier’, auch ‘Ungeheuer’; vgl. mnd. gūl, gūle ‘Pferd, Gaul, Hengst’, mnl. gūle, guul ‘(schlechtes) Pferd’, nl. (veraltet) guil ‘altes, schlechtes Pferd’. Nimmt man als Ausgangsbedeutung ‘geschlechtsreifes männliches Tier’ an, so kann an die Wurzel ie. *g̑heu- (s. ↗gießen) angeknüpft und Gaul, ähnlich wie ↗Ochse (s. d.), als ‘Samengießer’ gedeutet werden. Der heute vorherrschende verächtliche Sinn läßt sich neben positivem Gebrauch schon im 14./15. Jh. nachweisen.

Comment: The answer is good and correct. That's why I give +1. I also agree that one could have looked that up oneself. I still would prefer the answer to be a bit nicer in tone. I think, most German language learners are just not aware of the existence of online available german etymological dictionaries. Imho, this possibility could be taken into account, especially if the OP is new to german.se, as in this case. For instance like so: "There is a pretty good etymological dictionary available online: dwds.org. And it actually covers the etymology of _Gaul_: ... Nix für ungut.

Comment: Nicht direkt on-topic zur Frage: _"auch ‘Ungeheuer’"_ wirft bei mir die Frage auf, ob es da auch einen etymologischen Zusammenhang mit dem arabischen _Ghoul_ gibt?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ghul (das deutsche Wort dazu) findet sich leider im Pfeifer nicht. Wikipedia meint, daß der Ausdruck erst mit "1001 Nacht" und später Lovecraft im Deutschen Fuß fassen konnte - Also eher kein Zusammenhang.